# Create test build for ios using intel xdk

Tags: intel-xdk

How do I create a test build for ios using intel xdk? It asks for the certificate.

I am not a registered developer at apple dev. yet and would first like to deploy my application on a test device.

I tried to use ios CSR generated by intel XDK and on upload:
[image]

I had to change the extension from csr to cer as it does not accept csr extension.

and after changing to cer, it gives that error as in the picture.

Comment: here is step by step instructions, try this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/building-cordova-ios-apps-intel-xdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to test on an Apple device without an Apple Developer account.  When you get an account set up, then you should be able to follow these instructions:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/building-cordova-ios-apps-intel-xdk

which include the following requirements:

- An iOS device for on-device testing.
- Your **Apple iOS developer account**.

Sorry about that, but it seems to be an Apple requirement.